# ASP.net MVC Website is taking more time to redirect to payment gateway site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

Question :Website is taking more time to redirect to payment gateway site

When I click on my ASP.net website to pay and it redirects to payment gateway site , at this point it is taking more time than usual , Please help me with the possible issues and solutions.

Comment: 'More' compared to what!!! You need to provide information about how you are redirecting to the payment gateway / share some code, for someone to help you out.

Comment: Thanks,...'More' means as usual it takes 10 seconds to redirect page but now it is taking a minute to redirect to payment gateway.                                                      
-------------------------------
<add key="SamlJar" value="Payment gateway.jar" />

    <add key="pwDestinationUrl" value="payment gateway url" />

    <add key="pwFormName" value="data" />

    <add key="pwSamlAssertionName" value="SAMLResponse" />

    <add key="pwRelayState" value="Pwf" />